# If $ \bigcup N_\alpha $ is stationary, then $ \{ \min(N_\alpha) \}$ is stationary

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

It's the last set-theoretic question for tonight, I promise.

I'm trying to figure out why the following holds true:

Suppose we have a regular, uncountable cardinal $ \kappa $ and a disjoint family of non-stationary subsets $ \{ N_\alpha \subset \kappa, \alpha < \kappa \} $. Then the sum $ \bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \kappa} N_\alpha $ is stationary if and only if the set $ \{\min(N_\alpha), \alpha < \kappa\}$ is stationary.

The $ \Leftarrow $ direction is obvious. For the other one, suppose that $ C \in \kappa $ is a club, and $ C $ intersects some $ N_\alpha $. I can't see how the fact that they are disjoint and non-stationary might mean that $ C $ contains a minimum. I would appreciate a hint

Comment: HINT: Fodor's lemma . . .

Comment: To add on what @Noah said: when you see stationary sets, always think about Fodor.

Comment: @Asaf: I think about a depressing lemon, myself. (I learned the name *Fodor’s lemma* quite a bit later.)

Comment: @Brian: That's... depressing? :-P

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So should this be tagged elemontary-set-theory? (Sorry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: It seems easier to show the contrapositive of the forward implication. Suppose that $C$ is a club disjoint from $\{\min N_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$.

- Show that for each $\alpha<\kappa$ the set $C\cap\min N_\alpha$ has a maximum element $\gamma_\alpha$.

Define $f:\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}N_\alpha\to\kappa$ by

$$\large f(\xi)=\gamma_{\min\{\alpha<\kappa:\xi\in N_\alpha\}}\;,$$

and observe that $f$ is regressive (a pressing-down function). Is there any stationary set on which $f$ is constant?

Comment: Is $ f(\xi) $ well defined? If two $ N_\alpha $'s intersect, what's its value?

Comment: @Jytug: You said that the $N_\alpha$ are disjoint.

Comment: The family is disjoint, not necessarily pairwise. It's probably not so important

Comment: @Jytug: See the modified version of my answer.

Comment: @Jytug Disjoint means pairwise disjoint. What else could it mean here? You mean $\bigcap\{N_\alpha:\alpha\lt\kappa\}=\emptyset$? That hypothesis would be worthless; you could have $N_0=\{0\}$ and $N_\alpha=\{1,\alpha\}$ for all $\alpha\gt0.$

Comment: @bof of course you're right. It's late and I'm not thinking right

Comment: @Jytug: And I simply decided not to worry about it, since there was an easy out. `:-)`